# How to pass props from menu to menu items in Antd library?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I used the latest method recommended by the **Antd** to build the menu (https://ant.design/components/menu/#header). But the official document does not provide a method for how to pass props. I want to **pass the project.id into menuItems from Menu component**, so 'edit' and 'delete' in menuItems can accept project.id and trigger different functions. I would like to ask if is there any way to pass props.

```js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { ListProps } from '../types';
import { Table, Dropdown, Menu, Button } from 'antd';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Pin } from 'components/Pin';
import { useEditProject } from 'utils/project';
import { DeleteOutlined, EditOutlined, MoreOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { useProjectModal } from '../hooks/useProjectModal';
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';

const List = ({ users, ...props }: ListProps) => {
  const { open } = useProjectModal();
  const { mutate } = useEditProject();
  const { startEdit } = useProjectModal();
  const pinProject = (id: number) => (pin: boolean) => mutate({ id, pin });
  const editProject = (id: number) => () => startEdit(id);

  const menuItems = [
    {
      key: 'edit',
      label: <ButtonItem type="link">Edit</ButtonItem>,
      icon: <EditOutlinedIcon />
      // onClick: editProject()
    },
    {
      key: 'delete',
      label: <ButtonItem type="link">Delete</ButtonItem>,
      icon: <DeleteOutlinedIcon />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Table
      rowKey={'id'}
      columns={[
        {
          render(value, project) {
            return (
              <Dropdown
                overlay={<Menu items={menuItems} />}
                trigger={['click']}
              >
                <MoreOutlinedIcon />
              </Dropdown>
            );
          }
        }
      ]}
      {...props}
    ></Table>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. `MenuProps['items']` and `MenuProps['onClick']` refer to the property `items` and `onClick` in `<Menu />` respectively.

```js
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';

const List = ({ users, ...props }: ListProps) => {

  class Constants {
    public static readonly EDIT: string = 'EDIT';
    public static readonly DELETE: string = 'DELETE';
  }

  const menuItems: MenuProps['items'] = [
    {
      key: EDIT,
      label: <ButtonItem type="link">Edit</ButtonItem>,
      icon: <EditOutlinedIcon />
    },
    {
      key: DELETE,
      label: <ButtonItem type="link">Delete</ButtonItem>,
      icon: <DeleteOutlinedIcon />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Table
      rowKey={'id'}
      columns={[
        {
          render(value, project) {
            return (
              <Dropdown
                overlay={
                    <Menu 
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        switch (e.key) {
                          case Constants.EDIT:
                            startEdit(project.id);
                            break;
                          case Constants.DELETE:
                            break;
                        }
                      }}
                      items={menuItems} />
                }
                trigger={['click']}
              >
                <MoreOutlinedIcon />
              </Dropdown>
            );
          }
        }
      ]}
      {...props}
    ></Table>
  );
};

export default List;
```